# Drag & Drop on Dock icon in Cocoa - Messes up file associations

Tags: cocoa, icons, kernel-extension

I've implemented a drag-and-drop function in my application. The app let's you open `.kext` files.

I've used `-(void)application:openFiles:` as well as having set the Document Types:
[image: Document Types setup]

All works well, and my app can detect when the kext is dropped. However, when a Kext is dropped, all kexts on my Mac change icon to Folder icon! I guess it has something to do with my app messing with the file associations.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, the answer was simple: Tick the Document is distributed as Bundle box in the Document Types area, and the Icon doesn't change.